# Delete a row starting at a specific row, Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
wsIMP.Columns(4).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
```

The code will delete everything in D that is an empty cell, which I want, is there a way to add more into this code to start at row 6?

I though it would be simple like .Rows(6).Columns(4), but it doesn't seem to work. Anyone got an idea how to make this work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
wsIMP.Range("D6","D" & wsIMP.rows.count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: I was just posting something similar, but I will post mine since it's a bit different and may lead to better performance, so Excel doesn't try to delete all the empty rows under the dataset for no reason.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I agree with your approach but the OP's original code was deleting all the blank rows too so I didn't find it necessary to address. +1 for answering with intent to improve the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
dim lastrow as Long

With wsIMP
    lastrow = .Range("D" & .rows.count).end(xlup).Row 
    .Range("D6:D" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
End With
```

If you wish to write in one line, as in your comment, do this.

`wsIMP.Range("D6:D" & wsIMP.Range("D" & wsIMP.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells ...`

But if you ask me, that is much harder to read.

Comment: That is what I  thought about doing, but I wasn't too sure if I could of kept it one lined or not. That's for verifying.

Comment: Although, the .rows.count come back with an error 13, mismatch, so I'll keep plugging though.

Comment: Re: mismatch error, I forget to add `.Row` to end of statement. Now it's fixed :)

Comment: Thanks, I actually find the one line easier to read for some reason :)  Thanks though. I will use this elsewhere I am sure.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I haven't worked with coding in excel too much, but I've done quite a bit in Access, and I feel like I remember using either .Colums(6)(4) or .columns(6,4) to do this, maybe give each of those a quick shot.  If neither of those work, I'm afraid I can't help.

Comment: I can only comment on my own posts, or I would have left it as a comment as you mentioned. I figured in the worst case, the OP wastes about a minute trying it, it doesn't work, and someone else posts the real answer later, and my answer gets ignored, and that seems to be pretty much what happened. I don't think my incorrect answer really caused any damage though.

Comment: Good enough, dude. I think I am just in a grumpy mood today :) Some days are like that, at times.

Comment: Haha I understand all too well.

Comment: It was frustrating for the first week when i couldn't leave comments!